# how to sort post in admin column by recently

Tags: custom-post-types, sort

i have created custom post type

my problem is:

in admin column, posts are sorted by ID

how can change it to date. In other words, i want to sort post by recently

Comment: I hope you do know that post ids are set to autoincrement and the oldest post will have the least id and so on. So unless you have some system that checks the missing post ids (of the ones deleted) and switches off Auto Increment and then adds new posts with old ids, the question doesn't stand.

Comment: @Ehsan - Unless I'm losing the plot, posts are **by default** sorted by date when viewing them in the Admin area.  If that is not what you want, most of the columns are sortable by clicking on the column header.

Comment: @SaurabhShukla - Users can edit the publish date of a Post after it has been created, so if Posts were to be ordered by ID (which they are not by default) then they wouldn't necessarily be in date order.

Comment: @DavidGard Oh, that I didn't consider in this context thanks to the description I have.

Comment: @DavidGard tanks. my problem is that you told about this: "losing the plot, posts are by default sorted by date when viewing them in the Admin area"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add this part to function.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'example_func', 1 );
  function example_func( $query ) {
   if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
     $query->set( 'order' , 'DESC' );
   }
   return $query;
}
```

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_post_sort', 1 );
function change_post_sort( $query ) {
        if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'order' , 'DESC' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified');
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code snippet, thanks.